# OutAttribute и out keyword

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

В чём заключается разница между ключевым словом out и атрибутом Out?
На сколько мне известно из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute(v=vs.71).aspx), эти вещи эквивалентны.

Но как же тогда объясняется следующая проблема: при импорте WinAPI функции некоторый из её параметров оказывается ссылочным; при указании атрибута Out вызов функции приводит к ошибке 87 (неверный параметр), но если использовать ключевое слово out, такой проблемы не возникает?

Answer (score 2):

Ключевое слово `out` при компиляции преобразуется в комбинацию атрибута `[Out]` и ссылочного типа (того самого, который обозначается ключевым словом `ref`).

Очевидно, вы забыли про `ref` - отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: ref невозможно использовать вместе с OutAttribute. Нужно указывать одновременно In: `[In, Out] ref type param`. Я как то даже не пойму смысл атрибута Out, если есть ключевое слово и при этом он даже не взаимозаменяем (`[Out] type param != out type param`). Какой то ref ещё нужен. Мне проще атрибут не ставить, а сразу out написать.

Comment: Я понимаю если бы `[Out] type param <=> out type param`, но ведь `[In, Out] ref type param`.

Comment: Могу я в WinAPI функцию с ссылочным типом параметров передавать аргументы без ключевых слов?

Comment: `ref невозможно использовать вместе с OutAttribute` - потому что в противном случае будет неоднозначность.

Comment: `Мне проще атрибут не ставить, а сразу out написать.` - Бинго!

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815276/what-is-the-difference-between-in-out-and-ref-when-using-pinvoke-in-c)(Далее вольный перевод):

`[In]` и `[Out]` используются, что бы разрешить двусмысленность при работе с указателями.
`[In]` всегда ставится неявно по умолчанию=> явно его можно не указывать.

Однако, если ты хочешь получить какие-то изменения на вызывающей стороне, то должен указать атрибут `[Out]` явно.

Иногда, что бы увидеть изменения в переменной не нужно указывать [Out], например если тип является [bittable](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/marshalling-with-csharp-simple-types.html).

> Большинство типов данных имеют общее представления и для managed, и
>   для unmanaged памяти, и не требуют специальной обработки. Эти типы
>   называют blittable, потому что они не требуют специальной обработки
>   при передачи между managed и unmanaged кодом. Другие типы, которые
>   требуют специальных преобразований, называются non-blittable. Вы
>   можете думать, что большинство простых типов являются blittable, и все
>   составные типы являются non-blittable.

Comment: Hans ошибся там походу. Вместо "they don't specify the data flow" должно быть "they specify the data flow"